# How do I simulate the "back" button in an electron app?

Tags: shortcut-keys, navigation, electron

I am using Prospect Mail, which I understand to be an electron app. If I click on a link within an email, it takes me to the link destination. At that point I cannot get back to my email inbox -- even through closing the app.

Is there a way to simulate the back button in an electron app, or otherwise go back to the original root?

I find nothing in the documentation [here](https://github.com/julian-alarcon/prospect-mail).

Comment: What happens when you press Backspace or Alt-Left Arrow?

Comment: Thank you, @muru, for the response. In my example, there is a video in the new page. The arrow key only executes video controls. the "ctl + [" key seems to have no effect nor does the "alt + <-" key work.

Comment: Can you press Tab to force the focus to move outside the video?

Comment: @muru; Doesn't seem to work. Also tried clicking away, scrolling down the page so the video is not in view ... nada.